# Laravel 4 interface file error: "syntax error, unexpected 'interface' (T_INTERFACE)"

Tags: laravel, interface, laravel-4, syntax-error, repository-pattern

When trying to do any actions that invoke my Repo class, I get the following error on the child Repo interface:

```
"syntax error, unexpected 'interface' (T_INTERFACE)"
```

Here is the code for the Repo class, and the child repo interface file that is the source of the error:

```
<?php namespace MyProj\Repository\Parent;

use MyProj\Parent;
use MyProj\Parent\ChildRsrc as ChildRsrc;

class EloquentParentRepo implements ParentRepoIfc 
{
    public $childRepo;

    public function __construct(ChildRsrcRepoIfc $childRepo)
    {
        $this->childRepo = $childRepo;
    }
    // ...
    }
```

and the child repo interface file:

```
<?php namespace MyProj\Repository\Parent;

interface ChildRscrRepoIfc  // the error info points to this line
{
    public function all();

    public function create($input);

    public function delete($id);

    public function find($id);
}
```

It all is structured just like other code in the project that works fine.  The ChildRsrcRepoIfc and its concrete implementation (EloquentChildRscrRepo) are in the same Parent namespace as everything else referenced here.  I've triple-checked all spelling for typos.  Any help is appreciated, as always.

Update:  I tried removing the DI in the parent class and using direct instantiation but still got the same error:

```
class EloquentParentRepo implements ParentRepoIfc 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->childRepo = new ChildRsrcRepoIfc;
  //...
```

And I double checked that I am doing the binding in the Repo Svc Provider as follows:

```
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    public function register()
    {
     $this->app->singleton(
       'MyProj\Repository\Parent\ChildRsrcRepoIfc',
       'MyProj\Repository\Parent\EloquentChildRsrcRepo'
     );
```

Comment: Where is your `EloquentChildRsrcRepo` ? Your singleton is poiting to somethig that does not exists?

Comment: All the files are in the same namespace folder, `MyProj\Repository\Parent`.  There are a number of child tables that I have set up separate ChildRsrcNRepoIfc anc EloquentChildRsrcNRepo files for.  These child tables and their repo counterparts are mostly referenced in context of the parent, so I organized it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this be?:

```
class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
    public function register()
    {
     $this->app->singleton(
       'MyProj\Repository\Parent\ChildRsrcRepoIfc',
       'MyProj\Repository\Parent\EloquentParentRepo '
     );
```

Something that happened to me once while using Laravel IoC automatic resolution was writing

```
<?
```

Instead of

```
<?php
```

Laravel cannot find the file if you do this. Check your files.

Comment: Hm... I am binding the ParentRepoIfc to the EloquentParentRepo, and each of the children RepoIfc's to their own EloquentChildNRepo.  If I bind them to the parent - how then would I call the methods on the child repo to do DML on the child tables?

Comment: Yeah, I thought you might have more files involved, but PHP is complainting of something it shouldn't, so you must have something odd in your code. Edited to add one little thing.

Comment: I made the error go away by carefully deleting then re-entering all the whitespace in the file.  I think some corrupt invisible characters may have been the result of copy+paste from outside sources.  Several other of my files had the same problem.  Thank you for your frequent presence and help, @Antonio